# TextMesh Pro not compatible with LWRP

Tags: unity-game-engine

So after switching to LWRP I'm having some issues with TextMeshPro. Any TextMeshPro object that's in world space get's all in one position when I use LWRP. HUD elements work just fine.
example:

[image]

the texts in center of screen each should be on the white space of airplanes...
It's seems to be a shader issue because if I switch the shader on my font mat to LWRP shaders they work as normal, except they look horrible.

when i try to upgrade the font material i get :

> material was not upgraded. There's no upgrader to convert
>   TextMeshPro/Mobile/Distance Field shader to selected pipeline

how can i fix this issue?

Comment: You can't use legacy shader with SRPs, you can upgrade your materials through Edit/Render Pipeline/YourSRP/Upgrade blabla

Comment: @Jichael i get this error when trying to upgrade: material was not upgraded. There's no upgrader to convert TextMeshPro/Mobile/Distance Field shader to selected pipeline

Comment: Are you on the lastest version of TMP ? I'm using URP myself and everything is working fine (small tip, if you're not targeting mobile only, you can change you tet's shader to TextMeshPro/DistanceField instead of df mobile. Go to your package manager and update any plugins you have installed

Comment: @Jichael yes its the latest version, of course i use https://github.com/mnarimani/RTLTMPro on top of it. i tried TextMeshPro/DistanceField instead and it does't worked. every plugin is updated... :(

Comment: Do you need this plugin ? I'm pretty sure TMP already support RTL (there is a checkbox just below the textarea of any TMP component)

Comment: @Jichael i checked TMP without the additional plugin and the problem still remains...
I should mention that this problem happens only in "some" devices.